# Ubuntu 22.04.3 keeps freezing with double screen

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, freeze

I recently updated Ubuntu to 22.04.3 LTS and when I have an external screen the system freezes while using Chrome and few other applications.

It happened several times while watching videos on Youtube, filling some Google document and once in a Skype call. Both screens suddenly freeze, the audio and everything else keeps working (when it happened during a Skype call, the call went on for 20 more minutes, I could hear and speak, and the camera was working as well). I can move the cursor, but when I move it from a screen to another it immediately stops as well. The keyboard is also unresponsive.

I also seem to not be able to connect the laptop to a TV. If I connect it to a second monitor it works well and just freezes at a certain point, but if I connect to a TV the screen becomes black, the cursor appears and disappears, and when I unplug the ethernet cable the laptop goes back to normal.

It NEVER happened before I updated the system. I made sure that the NVIDIA graphic drivers are updated, and I also updated the BIOS. The freezing also NEVER happens while using the laptop without a second screen.

I am desperate. Any ideas?

In case it helps, the output of `lshw -C display` is

```
   *-display                 
   description: 3D controller
   product: TU117M [GeForce MX550]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom fb
   configuration: depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:190 memory:8e000000-8effffff memory:6000000000-600fffffff memory:6010000000-6011ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)

   *-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   version: 0c
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
   configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:189 memory:6072000000-6072ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

Comment: Try finding the correct version of the nvidia driver to install, or downgrade the nvidia driver and the kernel.